# How do you resolve conflicting sub-dependencies with pipenv?

Tags: pipenv

I have conflicting sub-dependencies from packages that installed via pipenv, which are preventing me from generating a Pipfile.lock. The conflict is with html5lib which is a dependency of spaCy and JupyterLab. spaCy explicitly requires version `1.0b8`, and bleach (which is a sub-dependency of JupyterLab) explicitly forbids `1.0b8`. (The relevant snippet from `pipenv graph` is below.)

Does anyone know how best to resolve this conflict? I couldn't find any information on pipenv's website about resolving conflicts.

```
en-core-web-lg==2.0.0
  - spacy [required: >=2.0.0a18, installed: 2.0.9]
    - html5lib [required: ==1.0b8, installed: 1.0b8]
jupyterlab==0.31.12
  - jupyterlab-launcher [required: >=0.10.0,<0.11.0, installed: 0.10.5]
    - notebook [required: >=4.2.0, installed: 5.4.1]
      - nbconvert [required: Any, installed: 5.3.1]
        - bleach [required: Any, installed: 2.1.3]
          - html5lib [required: !=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,!=1.0b1,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b3,>=0.99999999pre,!=1.0b2, installed: 1.0b8]
```

Comment: Hmm I think it is an issue I face [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/484) and which someone tried to solve [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1716) tell me if it helped you. I felt the pain they had to face the problem